# mysql middle ground between lock in share mode and lock for update?

Tags: mysql, locking

I am trying to find a middle ground between lock in share mode and lock for update.

It looks like lock in share mode can be acquired by two different transactions as long as the row being modified has not been updated. This sucks in the following scenario:

- t1 begin
- t1 read lock on X
- t2 begin
- t2 read lock on X
- t2 check if X.foo == 0
- t1 update X.foo = 1
- t1 end
- t2 continue with bad logic since X.foo != 0

The alternative I could use is lock for update, but that is too restrictive for my application because I don't care if my users read values that are 10 seconds old. So I never want to use lock for update.

QUESTION: Is there a lock I can use which:

1. is exclusive
2. allows reads on the row without getting the lock

Example:

- t1 my_lock row X
- t2 my_lock row X => NOT ALLOWED
- t3 select row X => ALLOWED, returning the latest committed data like lock in share mode

EDITS:
I am using NDB cluster as my storage engine. 
Server version: 5.1.56-ndb-7.1.15a-cluster-gpl-log MySQL Cluster Server (GPL)

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using INNODB as your storage engine? Also, which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about what you're doing, it's hard to know exactly to recommend. But here are a couple pointers that might help you get to the answer.

To begin with, a normal `SELECT ... FROM ...` doesn't do **any** locking on **any** rows and provides a *consistent* read -- that is it provides a result set based on what was in the database at the time the SELECT statement began.

This is important to know because the only time locking is an issue is if:

- multiple statements are concurrently trying to update the same data, or
- you for some reason want updates done in the middle of a long `SELECT` statement to be reflected in the results. (I'm not sure why this would ever be valid.)

Secondly, rows that are locked for other kinds of statements (`SELECT ... FROM ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`, for example) will depend on the INDEXES used to select the rows being updated. Basically, ALL ROWS OF AN INDEX SCANNED to locate the row will be locked.

This is critical because you can dramatically reduce the number of rows locked by crafting indexes that allow your `UPDATE` statements to select the rows to be updated directly. If you can, for example, create a `UNIQUE` index on the table and then have the UPDATE statement hit that INDEX when it's running the update, then only that row will be locked.

So the best luck I've had getting around locking problems is taking these two pieces of information -- 1) that normal SELECTS don't do any locking, and 2) that I can define good indexes to minimize the rows that actually do get locked -- and then designing sql that resulted in no locking conflicts.

Here's a link to a page that always helped me resolve any issues I've had with locking. It describes specifically each kind of statement that generates locks and what kinds of locks they are: [Locks Set by Different SQL Statements in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?  I recommend using InnoDB and using transaction isolation levels with MVCC to achieve the level of concurrency you want.

Due to MVCC, a normal select in InnoDB doesn't lock.  So you'll never block readers.